# Index not found when having cluster name in URL path

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a local ES container running http://elasticsearch.net:9202 and i see a cluster by the name elasticsearch-dev with 1 node in it .
When i make a Postman call to it like the following http://elasticsearch.localnet:9202/elasticsearch-dev/*/_search?q=order_number:102811901637201
I get

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "index_not_found_exception",
                "reason": "no such index",
                "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
                "resource.id": "elasticsearch-dev",
                "index_uuid": "_na_",
                "index": "elasticsearch-dev" --------------------------- cluster name is reported back in as index name.
            }
        ],
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index",
        "resource.type": "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id": "elasticsearch-dev",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "elasticsearch-dev"
    },
    "status": 404
}
```

But if i query like http://elasticsearch.localnet:9202/*/_search?q=order_number:102811901637201. without the cluster name it works fine (200 response) .

Does ES cluster deployed locally (1 node )have a different URL pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running elasticsearch in your local system, the URL for index or search API is in the below format

```
http://{{hostname}}:{{es-port}}/{{index-name}}/_search
```

When running Elasticsearch in AWS EC2 instance, in that case also you can use this URL :

```
http://{{public-ip-of-cluster}}:{{es-port}}/{{index-name}}/_search
```

Comment: Is that as per the design ? I mean like the URL querying differs when it is running locally vs running in say AWS (for instance).

Comment: @user7246161 please go through the updated part of the answer